# How to disregard numbers when reading from a text file?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, arraylist

Right now I want to store a text file that goes like this:

1 apple

2 banana

3 orange

4 lynx

5 cappuccino

and so on into a data structure. Would the best way of doing this be mapping the int to the string somehow, or should I make an arraylist? I'm supposed to, when I store the words themselves, disregard the int and any whitespace, and keep only the word itself. How do I disregard the int when reading in lines? Here is my hacked together code right now:

```
  public Dictionary(String filename) throws IOException {
  if (filename==null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null filename");
  else{
      try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String str;
            int numLines=0;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                numLines++;
            }
            String[] words=new String[numLines];
            for (int i=0; i<words.length;i++){
                words[i]=in.readLine();
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
```

}

Thank you in advance for the help!!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have already read the file data when counting the lines. So there are no data to read in the second for-cycle. Use a Java Collection to store a dynamically growing set of lines. You will not need to count them before storing them to a Java object hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement the power of the regular expression:

```
List texts<String> = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9\\s]+"); 
String text = "1 apple 2 oranges 3 carrots"; 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text); 

while (matcher.find()) { 
  texts.add(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

regular expressions are very much popular these days. the compile method is used for compiling your search pattern, with the numbers you see in the parameter is to prevent getting them on your search. So it's completely safe. use apache's IOUtilities to convert a text file to String

Comment: I'm not actually sure what regular expressions are...what does Pattern.compile("[^0-9\\s]+") mean? Also it's input as a text file rather than a string...so for this to work do I have to convert the text file into a string? Thank you for the help.

Comment: regular expressions are very much popular these days. the compile method is used for compiling your search pattern, with the numbers you see in the parameter is to prevent getting them on your search. So it's completely safe. use apache's IOUtilities to convert a text file to String

Answer (score 2):

This won´t work because you are already at the end of the file, so the in.readLine() methode will return null.

I would use a Map to store the name and the amount...something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

while( (line = br.readLine() !=null){
    //also check if the array is null and the right size, trim, etc.
    String[] tmp = line.split(" ");
    map.put(tmp[1], Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]) );
}
```

Otherwise you can try it with the Scanner class. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can give `regular expressions` a try.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^0-9\\s]+");
String s = "1 apple 2 oranges";

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output =

> apple
>
> oranges

To get a idea about regular expressions [Java regex tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a `List` of items to store the results parsed from the file. One way to parse every text line is to use the `String.split(String)` method. Also note that you should handle exceptions in the code properly and do not forget to close the `Reader` when you are done (no matter whether flawlessly or with an exception => use a `finally` block). The following example should put you on track... Hope this helps.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.start("test.txt");
  }

  private void start(String filename) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(readFromFile(filename));
  }

  private final class Item {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    public Item(String name, int id) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Item [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }
  }

  private List<Item> readFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Reader r = null;
    try {
      r = new FileReader(filename);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lineItems = line.split(" ");
        if (lineItems.length != 2) {
          throw new IOException("Incorrect input file data format! Two space separated items expected on every line!");
        }
        try {
          int id = Integer.parseInt(lineItems[0]);
          Item i = new Item(lineItems[1], id);
          items.add(i);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
          throw new IOException("Incorrect input file data format!", ex); // JDK6+
        }
      }
    } finally {
      if (r != null) {
        r.close();
      }
    }
    return items;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your words don't contain spaces, you could use `String.split( " " )` to split up the `String` into an array of `Strings` delimited by spaces.

Then just take the second element of the array (the first will be the number).

Also, the `String.trim( )` method will remove any whitespace before or after the `String`.

Note: there's probably some error checking that you'd want to perform (what if the `String` isn't formatted as you expect). But this code snippet gives the basic idea:

```
...
String s = in.readLine( );
String[] tokens = s.split( " " );
words[i] = tokens[1].trim( );
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something easy just substring the original work by counting digits:

```
int t = 0;
while (word.charAt(t) >= '0' && word.charAt(t) <= '9')
  ++t;

word = word.substring(t);
```

If words NEVER contain spaces you can also use `word.split(" ")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

**I**nstead of using a buffer reader use the Scanner class and instead of using an Array use an ArrayList, like so :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Dictionary {
  private ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();

code...

public Dictionary(String fileName) throws IOException {

code...

try {
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new fileRead(fileName));

  ArrayList.add("Dummy"); // Dummy value to make the index start at 1
  while(inFile.hasNext()) {
    int n = inFile.nextInt(); // this line just reads in the int from the file and
                              // doesn't do anything with it
    String s = inFile.nextLine().trim();

    strings.add(s);
    }
  inFile.close(); // don't forget to close the file
}
```

and then since your data goes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, you can just use the index to retrieve each item's number.

By doing this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < strings.size(); i++) {
int n = i;
String s = n + " " + strings.get(i);
System.out.println(s);
}
```